# How to do text search in API Documentation of Here iOS SDK Premium Edition?

Tags: here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm developing an iOS project in Xcode using the Here SDK. I'm using the Premium Edition (v3.17).
I added the SDK to my project using CocoaPods. When I search my workspace I do not get any results from the HereSDK header files. E.g. when I search for "NMAProxyObject" I only get the results where I used that term in my own swift files.

The search function on the website gives much more results then the ones from the Premium iOS SDK.

Is there a way to search the API documentation of the premium iOS SDK only? Either through Xcode or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search in CocoaPods or other directories, you can define your own search scope in Xcode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you download the SDK package, you will be able to find Developer Guide pdf inside user-guide folder. Also you can find all api references inside api_reference_jazzy_html_bundle_3.17. Search option is also available on the pages.
[image]

Comment: I tried this already. The PDF does not have the full API Reference, and the search function inside the jazzy bundle doesn't seem to work. (I don't really know how to use that to be honest... I unpack the tar file, go into the folder and open index.html. (opens in Safari). When I enter a search term and hit enter, I get the raw json from search json. No search results.